# TCP connection timeout error code _COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766

Tags: c#, sql-server, sockets, tcp

I am a Newbie to TCP/IP programming in c#, so I am DESPERATE for a solution to my current problem!

I have designed a C# Windows application running under Windows 7 with a Sqlserver 2005 database. My application is trying to send an HL7 record over a TCP/IP connection, to a Unix Lab. system machine.

I can get a connection ok, and send the HL7. BUT I cannot get ANY reply from the Lab. server! the connection times-out with error code 10060, as well as a _COMPlusExceptionCode value of -532462766.

Here is a sample of my c# 'Connect' methods:

```
   buildSendHL7_TCPIP hl7Agent = new buildSendHL7_TCPIP();
```

// class 'buildSendHL7_TCPIP(); ' contains methods to build the HL7 segments, as well as methods to   send and receive messages over the TCP connection

```
   string strServerIPAddress = string.Empty;
   Int32 intSocketNo         = new Int32();
   bool sentOK               = false;

   /***********************************/
   /*Try send the HL7 to LIS-HORIZON...*/
   /***********************************/

   strServerIPAddress = "10.1.6.248";
   intSocketNo = 5910;

   sentOK = hl7Agent.SendHL7(strServerIPAddress, intSocketNo, strHL7_Record);
   if (!sentOK)
      {
          _strUIMessage = "*Error* HL7 Message NOT sent  to LIS!";
          opsMessageBox mb = new opsMessageBox(this);
          mb.ShowDialog();
          mb.Close();
          goto EndLabel;

       }
```

Here are the methods I've created to build a TCP connection and send the HL7 to the LIS Server:

```
public bool SendHL7(string strIPAddress, Int32 intSocket, string hl7message)
    {
        /* send the complete HL7 message to the server...*/
        int  port = (int)intSocket;
        IPAddress localAddr  = IPAddress.Parse(strIPAddress);


        try
        {
            // Add the leading & trailing character field-separator and CR  LineFeed' t.

            string llphl7message = null;
            llphl7message = "|";
            llphl7message += hl7message;
            llphl7message += Convert.ToChar(28).ToString();
            llphl7message += Convert.ToChar(13).ToString();

            // Get the size of the message that we have to send.
            Byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(llphl7message);
            Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];

            // Create a socket connection with the specified server and port.
            Socket s = ConnectSocket(localAddr, port);

            // If the socket could not get a connection, then return false.
            if (s == null)
                return false;

            // Send message to the server.

           s.Send(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.Length, 0);

            // Receive the response back
            int bytes = 0;
            s.ReceiveTimeout = 3000; /* 3 seconds wait before timeout */

            bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0); /*   IMEOUT occurs!!! */

            string page = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
            s.Close();

            // Check to see if it was successful
            if (page.Contains("MSA|AA"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SocketExecptionError:" + e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static Socket ConnectSocket(IPAddress server, int port)
    {
        Socket s = null;
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

        // Get host related information.
        hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

        foreach (IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
        {
            IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
            Socket tempSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);

            tempSocket.Connect(ipe);

            if (tempSocket.Connected)
            {
                s = tempSocket;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

I've been told that socket 5910 cannot receive ANY communications in Windows 7 due to Virus issues. Is this true?  If so, I tried to connect to ANOTHER server on our network (PACS/RIS) socket #  5556. I get the SAME timeout error message.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour looks like the server doesn't understand your request / doesn't recognize it as a complete message according to the expected protocol.

As I understand from your code you are sending a HL7 message. I don't know this protocol, according to google it could be Health Level 7. The example I found is starting with some text, then a | as a delimiter. Your message is starting with |. Maybe there is the problem...

So you should have a look if the message you send is matching the protocol definition.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Roland. The HL7 message block seems to be formatted properly according to our protocol. I did some further tests and it seems that there is a problem with the 'protocolOption' argument of the 'Socket' method. I've tried using IP, Tcp, IP4, IP6 etc. but no joy there also!

Comment: What gives you the idea that the problem is in the protocolOptions? As you can create a connection but don't get an answer I think there is a Problem in the protocol. Can you debug/trace on the server or do you have a working client to compare the messages sent with your messages?

Comment: Problem solved! The HL7 message segment that I was sending didn't have the obligatory 'Vertical Tab' at the start of the message! :-)